# Freezing time in Robolectric tests

Tags: robolectric, android-testing

Is there a way to fix the system clock at a time when running tests with Robolectric? I have some code that's dependent on the day of the week. In rspec, there's the TimeCop gem that allows you to fix a time for the system. Does Robolectric have an equivalent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't saw a ready to use feature for set explicit time/date yet.

You can achieve this by creating your own `ShadowSystemClock` implementation. Or shadow another class/function  from where the date is being collected.

Current `SystemClock` shadow implementation
https://github.com/robolectric/robolectric/blob/master/src/main/java/org/robolectric/shadows/ShadowSystemClock.java

Implement own shadow
http://robolectric.org/extending/

Comment: Thanks for that. I ended up coming at the problem from the other side and making my test data calculated based on the current time instead of freezing time for the test data. This looks like the right way to go if I need to add that function later.

Comment: When you run a test at midnight then the test behaves different than when it run at 3 pm? How you will ensure that you logic  behavior is full tested on different times/dates?

Comment: My tests are based on days. Rather than always testing objects with fixed dates and setting the system time while testing to be the date when I created the test, I found it cleaner and easier to create my testing objects with current dates.

Comment: If you use jodatime then and calls to DateTime.now() will use the real system time even if the ShadowSystemClock is being used. To overcome that do:

DateTimeUtils.setCurrentMillisFixed(fakeTime.getMillis());
SystemClock.setCurrentTimeMillis(fakeTime.getMillis());